# Javascript Oracle sql with parameter

Tags: javascript, oracle, neoload

I am trying to make SQL with variable.

```js
var PLid = '02101';
var connection = new Packages.SQLConnection("oracle");
connection.connect("server", port ,"SID", "test", "test");
var result = connection.getResults("select policy_no from policy where product_id = '"PLid"');
connection.disconnect();
```

I am getting the following error:

> missing ) after argument list (Script=script_2;Line=4)

If I rewrite what i found on the internet:

```js
var result = connection.getResults("select policy_no from policy where product_id = '?'",1);
```

> Can't find method SQLConnection.getResults(string,number). (Script=script_2;Line=4)

I am trying to implement this code in Neoload.

Comment: Try: `("select policy_no from policy where product_id = " + PLid);`

Comment: @rweris Do you still have the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate strings in JavaScript you need `+`. Change the fourth line to this:

```
var result = connection.getResults("select policy_no from policy where product_id = '"+PLid+"')
```

If `PLid` can be set as an integer (`var PLid = 2101;`), you can skip the single quotation marks, like this:

```
var result = connection.getResults("select policy_no from policy where product_id = "+PLid)
```